# Including a precompiled header and a non-precompiled header in a .cpp file causes the .cpp file to not recognize the non-precompiled header

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Visual Studio 2022:

I included a simple header to store basic functions like printing text or executing functions to my .cpp file, but after including a precompiled header that stores Windows.h the .cpp file doesn't recognize the functions/variables inside of the non-precompiled header.

CPP:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "basics.h"
#include "precompiled header.h"

int main()
{
    Basics::Print("Something"); // C2653 Basics is not a class or namespace name
}
```

basics.h:

```cpp
class Basics
{
public:
   static void Print(const char* format, ...);
}
```

precompiled header.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h> 

// This header is than #included in a .cpp file.
```

- What is the point of precompiling the headers if some headers need other headers but can't access them since only .cpp files can? Do you really want to precompile headers + Include headers in another headers that need them.

Comment: Shouldn't precompiled header be the first one in each translation unit?

Comment: Why does your CPP file have `#pragma once` in it?

Comment: @Eljay why not? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: *Why not?*  Because [`#pragma once`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/once?view=msvc-170) is to ensure a *header* file is only *included* once.  A CPP file is not a header file.

Comment: @Eljay it's not uncommon to put `#pragma once` in a source file, because then it applies to everything included in that source.

Comment: @MarkRansom • How many times do you `#include` a `*.cpp` file in a translation unit?  Or else I suspect one of us doesn't have a firm grasp of `#pragma once`.

Comment: @Eljay my understanding of `#pragma once` is that it instructs the compiler to track included files and ignore any `#include` it's already seen, no matter the file's extension.  It doesn't matter if the `#pragma once` is in the source or a header, it will have the same effect - and that effect will apply to the whole translation unit from that point forward.

Comment: @Eljay P.S. it's not uncommon for header files to include other headers themselves, so even if you *know* you're only including a file once the `#pragma once` can be of some benefit.

Comment: @MarkRansom • we're not talking header files, the context is putting `#pragma once` in the `*.cpp` source file.

Comment: @Eljay you're missing my point completely!  It doesn't matter if the `pragma once` is in a source or a header, or how many there are - all you need is one, the earlier the better.  I believe Microsoft puts one in each of their standard includes.

Comment: @MarkRansom • You should try out your hypothesis.  It is not true.  Read the link I gave to MSDN on `#pragma once`.  It only affect the file it is in.  (And Microsoft's behavior isn't quite the same as GCC and Clang behavior, but that's a separate issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precompiled header must come first in the include list, because it erases everything that comes before it.

Comment: This solved my issue. Thank you Based Chad